# hplip gui required plugin

Tags: linux, printer, plugins, hplip

I downloaded hplip gui to manage my printer, but in order to set it up correctly, you must click the green puzzle piece labeled "install required plugin." Once you do, you are presented with two options: download it from HP's server or locate the file locally on your hard disk. In the past, I have had success with downloading it from HP's server. Currently, my luck is not as good. My question is simple. Where can I find the plugin on the Internet so that I might download it and install it using the second option of installing from my hard drive?